# Why does objdump show a null opcode for this assembly language instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, opcode, objdump

I have the following assembly code:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:

add byte [eax], al
```

After compiling and linking, I try to see the opcode:

```
$ objdump -d eax.o

eax.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
        ...
$
```

Why do I get a null opcode?

Comment: And what's wrong with null opcode? It's valid.

Comment: @michael I'd say that qualifies as an answer, unless you think the question should be closed instead. Looks like a reasonable one to me, though.

Comment: @CodyGray : I agree, was searching for a possible duplicate and was typing up the answer as you commented. Thanks.

Comment: Usually this question is asked the other way around lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This instruction:

```
add byte [eax], al
```

Is encoded as the two byte [*ADD*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html) instruction 0x00 0x00:

> ```
> Opcode    Instruction     Op/En   64-bit Mode Compat/Leg Mode Description
> 00 /r     ADD r/m8, r8    MR      Valid       Valid           Add r8 to r/m8.
> ```

*OBJDUMP* by default will print blocks of repeated zeros as `...`. To change this behavior try using the `-z` option as described in the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html):

> -z --disassemble-zeroes
>
> Normally the disassembly output will skip blocks of zeroes. This option directs the disassembler to disassemble those blocks, just like any other data.

Your command could look like this:

```
objdump -z -d eax.o
```

The output should look something like:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering :))